# How to replace the last occurrence in a character?

Tags: r, regex

I have an R character vector:

```
a<-'aabbccaabbccaabbcc'
```

I want to replace the last occurrence of 'aa' and anything that follows with 'bb'.
I tried using `stri_replace_last` of `stringi` package with regex `(.*)aa(.*)`. But it replaces everything as it is a single string.

Is there any way to do this in R?

Comment: I feel as though I've seen this question before.

Comment: `gsub("aa[^a]*$", "bb", "aabbccaabbccaabbcc")`?

Comment: I tried searching for something similar but was not able to find it on stackoverflow

Comment: @akrun it wasn't me; as I've told you before: I don't downvote valid answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a <- 'aabbccaabbccaabbcc'
first <- gsub('^(.*)aa.*$', '\\1', a)
result <- paste0(first, paste(replicate(nchar(a) - nchar(first), "b"), collapse = ""))

> a
[1] "aabbccaabbccaabbcc"
> result
[1] "aabbccaabbccbbbbbb"
                 ^^ anything which follows the last 'aa' has been replaced with 'b'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gsubfn` to match the two 'a' followed by zero or more characters that are not an 'a' (`[^a]*`) until the end (`$`) of the string, replace the matched string by replicating 'b' by the number of characters of the matched string.

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("aa[^a]*$", ~strrep("b", nchar(x)), a) 
#[1] "aabbccaabbccbbbbbb"
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you even notice a down-vote? Your score is rounded to thousands. :)